# Serial Port Over Remote Desktop

Tags: c#, serial-port

need your help.

I have this scenario:

> I have to comunicate to a Printer connected to Serial Port, over remote Desktop, in bidirectional communication, it means, i want to send comands to the Serial Port, and get the response of the remote printer, all of this in Remote Desktop.

I successfull can connect locally, i can send commands to the printer in the remote Desktop with a Spooler, but locally i can get the response that the Printer sends me when all finish (close Fiscal Document).

I have tried with c#, but this only works when i the Printer is connected in my local machine.

I am sharing ports, printers in my remote desktop communication, but i cannot get any response from the remote Printer.

How can i do that?

Any help, will be appreciated.
Normally I will send some code, but, i just want some help of you telling me if that is possible, or maybe if you have some examples or guides.

Regards

Comment: I think if the remote PC has Files and Printer Sharing off, it won't let you do that.

Comment: well, the  remote desktop has Files, Printers and Ports sharing, i am sure of that

Comment: Then the only thing i can see is a firewall blocking the communication somehow...

Comment: you was right!, was Firewall problem, you should answer this and i will accept that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firewall is blocking communications.